# Struggling with pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

I thought I understood basic concepts of pointers as per C tutorials, but I really get confused when actually coding.  I have some questions:

1 - Lets say I have:

```
customList arrayOfLists[3]; //global
//...
void someMethod()
{
   int i;
   for (i=0; i<3; i++)
   {
        customList l = arrayOfLists[i];

        //METHOD1
        //Next time I come back to this function, element is still there!
        removeFirstElement(&l);              

        //METHOD2
        //Next time I come back to thsi function, element is gone!
        //removeFirstElement(&(arrayOfLists[i])); 
   }
}
```

Why would both Method1 and Method2 not work the same way?  In both cases I am basically saying remove the first element of the list located at addressX.  Does it create a copy of the array?

2 - What is the difference between:

```
struct1.ptr1->ptr2->someIntValue //1
&(struct1).ptr1->ptr2->someIntValue //2
```

The 2nd way doesn't make sense to me and I don't really know what's going on there, but it seems to work. I was expecting the 1st way to work but it is not giving me the right answer.

3 - Lets say I do this:

```
ptr2 = ptrToStruct;
ptr1 = ptr2;
ptr2->intProp = 5;
ptr2 = ptrToStruct2;
```

Is ptr1 pointing to the initial memory location still, or is it the same ptr2?  What is ptr1->intProp?

Thanks.

Comment: `customList` is a typedef that hides its pointerness, right? Something like `typedef struct mystruct *customList`? ??

Comment: You might like to read [the c-faq](http://c-faq.com). Especially section 6.

Comment: yes that's right it is a typedef

Comment: Some people (me included) like to always see the `*` when dealing with pointers. By hiding the pointerness you make it easier to mix the types the wrong way in some situations.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers are hard to grasp because they are abstracting the memory of the computer without referring to that memory in the description of the operation you can do with pointers.

Pointers are much easier to understand if you learn a bit of assembler.

Answer (score 0):

```
customList l = arrayOfLists[i];
//METHOD1
//Next time I come back to this function, element is still there!
removeFirstElement(&l);
```

This is wrong: you need something like:

```
customList *l = &arrayOfLists[i];
removeFirstElement(l);
```

For the second question:

```
struct1.ptr1->ptr2->someIntValue // this will give you someIntValue
&(struct1).ptr1->ptr2->someIntValue // this will give you the address of memory where someIntValue is stored
```

Answer (score 0):

Q3)

```
ptr2 = ptrToStruct;
ptr1 = ptr2;
ptr2->intProp = 5;
ptr2 = ptrToStruct2;
```

> Is ptr1 pointing to the initial memory location still, or is it the same ptr2?

Yes, `ptr1` points to the memory location where `ptrToStruct` is pointing to. Affecting `ptr2` to point to a different location (`ptrToStruct2`) doesn't affect `ptr1`.

> What is ptr1->intProp?

5.

Comment: @C-Noob - Check this example http://ideone.com/5GVlP. Also, think of @pmg answer. It's description is even simpler.

Answer (score 0):

1. `customList` is a local pointer; `arrayOfLists` is a global array. They live in different memory regions.
2. The `&` has lower precedence than `.` or `->`. If I were to simplify the 1st expression to `j`, the 2nd expression would be simplified as `&j`.
3. Pointers are just like any other type. In the code below

   ```
   int j, k;
   k = 5;
   j = k;
   k = 12;
   ```

   does j have 5 or 12?

Comment: Ok for #2, lets say I want to read or update someIntValue (change the actual integer value), I should use the 1st method?  Unfortunately its the 2nd that gets me the right int value so maybe something else is wrong in my program.

Comment: We'd need the declaration of your structures and definition of the objects to understand what is happening. I wrote a little example that "works" without the `address-of` operator: http://ideone.com/IyKce see lines 23 and 24

Answer (score 0):

For question 1, method 1 is taking the address of the variable `l`.  `l` is initialized to hold a *copy* the *value* of the `i`'th item of the array.  This is a completely different memory location.  Note that if the `removeFirstElement()` function depends on the the argument being a pointer to the array, it will fail miserably using method 1.

---

For question 2, line 2 is valid, but not for the reason you probably think.  What it evaluates to is getting the address of `struct1.ptr1->ptr2->someIntValue`.  Note that you did not take the address of the struct, but the member of the member of the member it was pointing to.  You probably meant it to be as:

```
(&struct1).ptr1->ptr2->someIntValue
```

This would fail miserably.

The member access operator (`.`) is used on struct values to access a member.  What you have on the LHS is a *pointer* to a struct and should be using the arrow operator (`->`) to access the member.  Or, dereference the pointer first, then use the dot (what the arrow operator is equivalent to).

```
(*(&struct1)).ptr1
/* is equivalent to: */
(&struct1)->ptr1
```

---

For question 3, assuming `ptr1` and `ptr2` are pointers to whatever struct `ptrToStruct` is pointing to, then yes, `ptr1` is still pointing to whatever it was pointing to.  You never modified the `ptr1` variable, only the struct that it was pointing to.  Since both `ptr1` and `ptr2` are pointing to the same structure (in other words, aliased), you should see the same value when accessing the member `ptr1->intProp`.